# Symfony 4 Form rendering with extra data

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have a Symfony form for a Location object that has embedded in it a list of activities. Each activity has a title, status menu, and a notes text field.

I do not want the user to edit the title but I still want to display it to the user.

How can I gain access to this variable from within the form template in formbuilder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can access form data through {{ form.vars.data.fieldName }} example:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}

    {{ form_row(form.name) }}<br> {# assume that the Location entity has a name property #}
    {{ form.vars.data.name}}<br> {# accessing the form data #}

    <button class="btn">{{ button_label|default('Save') }}</button>

{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Or with a child form:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}

    {{ form_row(form.name) }} {# assume that the Location entity has a name property #}

            {# iterate over each existing activity and render its fields #}
            {% for activity in form.activities %}
                {{ activity.vars.data.title }}<br> {# accessing the form data #}
                {{ form_row(activity.notes) }}<br><br> {# render a form field #}
            {% endfor %}

    <button class="btn">{{ button_label|default('Save') }}</button>

{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Use `{{ dump(form) }}` to dump the form's content on the screen